# Python - Script that copy certain files by file name

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a script to copy files with specific names from one folder to another.

The file name format I want to copy is 2021052444592AKC. However, the script I wrote copies all files with the ending AKC, but in the if condition I specified that it should copy only files if the filename starts with "202105" and ends with "AKC". In the folder I have other files in the same format that is"YYYYMMDD44592threeUpperCaseLetters"

Can anyone help, because I haven't found the answer to this problem, thanks in advance :)

P.S I'm using Python3 in PyCharm

```
import shutil
import os
os.chdir(r"C:\\")
# without a double backslash and the letter r, the compiler throws an error
dir_src = r"C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\1\\" 
dir_dst = r"C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\2\\" 
for filename in os.listdir(dir_src):
    if filename.startswith("202105") and filename.endswith("AKC"):
       shutil.copy(dir_src + filename, dir_dst)
print("End")
```

Comment: Are you sure the extra files are not leftover from previous versions of the code, while you worked on it ? I suggest you empty the destination folder, and re-run to make sure.

Comment: Yes I am sure before running the code I deleted all files from the target folder

Comment: I can't reproduce. Your code looks fine. General comments `r'a\\b'` will result in two backslashes in the path (which doesn't matter but still). Either do `r'a\b'` or 'a\\b'. There's also no reason for the `chdir` at the start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why your script is failing, but you might want to try a solution with a regular expression (re).

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^202105(\d{2})44592AKC$')

os.chdir(r"C:\\")
# without a double backslash and the letter r, the compiler throws an error
dir_src = r"C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\1\\" 
dir_dst = r"C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\2\\" 
for filename in os.listdir(dir_src):
    if pattern.match(filename):
       shutil.copy(dir_src + filename, dir_dst)
print("End")
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but the code I wrote was more understandable to me and I wrote it without any help on the web, so I'm proud of it :)